# pylint seems to not handle "from . import foo" style imports

Tags: python, pylint, import

If I do:

```
from . import foo
```

In a script and run pylint over it, I get:

> ```
> F:  1: Unable to import %r
> ```

Is there a way a work around for getting pylint to understand this syntax?

Comment: I'm running pylint 0.19.0 astng 0.19.3,

Answer (score 0):

Update to at least [pylint 0.18.1 / logilab-astng 0.19.1](http://lists.logilab.org/pipermail/python-projects/2009-August/002012.html)?

Comment: Yup, running that.  It's only when I use the dot specifically, e.g. from foo import bar works, but not from . import foo.

Comment: Ahh, got. The link I found was using a relative name.

Answer (score 0):

Note that the "from . import smthg" is only allowed in a Python package.

I've tested this with

```
pylint --version
No config file found, using default configuration
pylint 0.19.0, 
astng 0.19.1, common 0.46.0
Python 2.5.5 (r255:77872, Feb  1 2010, 19:53:42) 
[GCC 4.4.3]
```

and was not able to reproduce your problem:

```
alf@lacapelle:/tmp$ ls package/
foo.py  __init__.py  relative.py
alf@lacapelle:/tmp$ cat package/relative.py 
from . import foo

alf@lacapelle:/tmp$ pylint -r n package/
No config file found, using default configuration
************* Module package
C:  1: Missing docstring
************* Module package.foo
C:  1: Black listed name "foo"
C:  1: Missing docstring
************* Module package.relative
C:  1: Missing docstring
W:  1: Unused import foo
```